# Rules language : How to deal with comparing between 2 objects of the same class?

Tags: drools, rules

I have a class :

```
public class FootballPlayer() {

    private int scoredGoals;
    //... some other attributes and some getters and setters
}
```

I need in my drools file to have a rule to decide who is a better player between 2 comapred players.

The difficulty that I cross is how to compare between the two objects of the same class?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Don't tag this with Java: you'll get all sorts of fallout...

Comment: oh you're right! thank you for the suggested edit. :)

Comment: OK, one answer was retracted. - BTW, much more can be said about "comparing two objects of the sme class".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difficulty, only a minor cliff that has to be circumnavigated.

```
rule "A better scorer"
when
    $f1: FootballPlayer( $score1; scoredGoals )
    $f2: FootballPlayer( $score2; scoredGoals > $score1 )
then
    System.out.println( $f2.getName() + " is better than " + $f1.getName() );
end
```

Of course, it's possible that two players tie:

```
rule "Two scorers with equal cpability"
when
    $f1: FootballPlayer( $score1; scoredGoals )
    $f2: FootballPlayer( this != $f1, $score2; scoredGoals == $score1 )
then
    System.out.println( $f2.getName() + " and " + $f1.getName() + " are in the same class" );
end
```

Note the constraint ensuring that the second one isn't idenfical to the first one! (This is the "cliff".)

You might also be interested in a rule to determine the best:

```
rule "The best scorer"
when
    $f1: FootballPlayer( $score1; scoredGoals )
    not FootballPlayer( scoredGoals > $score1 )
then
    System.out.println( $$f1.getName() + " is the best" );
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I would propose is to implements the comparable interface; that way you
will be able to sort a list of player depending on the scoreGoals .

```
public class FootballPlayer implements Comparable<FootballPlayer>
{
    private int scoredGoals;

    public FootballPlayer(int scoredGoals)
    {
        this.scoredGoals = scoredGoals;
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        FootballPlayer a = new FootballPlayer(10);
        FootballPlayer b = new FootballPlayer(5);
        FootballPlayer c = new FootballPlayer(15);
        List<FootballPlayer> fps = new ArrayList<FootballPlayer>();
        fps.add(a);
        fps.add(b);
        fps.add(c);
        Collections.sort(fps);
        for (FootballPlayer fp : fps)
        {
            System.out.println(fp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return " -- " + scoredGoals;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(FootballPlayer o)
    {
        if (o == null)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (o.scoredGoals < this.scoredGoals)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (o.scoredGoals > this.scoredGoals)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry: this isn't Java: it is Drools!

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstabning